# NuGet.exe command-line update to specific version

Tags: .net, nuget

The NuGet [`Update-Package`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Update-Package) PowerShell command which can be run from inside Visual Studio has supported for a `-Version` flag which allows updating to a specific version of a package.

It is a big limitation for our build server workflow that the [`nuget.exe update`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Update_Command) command doesn't support this scenario, and I am thinking of two options:

1. Modify the nuget.exe command line tool source code. This doesn't seem hard, there already seems to be support for calling `UpdatePackageReference` with a version specification, which is used by the `-Safe` switch.
2. Write a command-line extension (e.g. as explained [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/robz/archive/2011/07/15/extend-nuget-command-line.aspx)), similar to [NuGet.Analyze](https://github.com/xavierdecoster/NuGet.Analyze), that adds a version-specific update command to nuget.exe. From what I can tell, though, this will require duplicating most of the code in the `UpdateCommand` class, is most of its key methods are internal or private.

Does anyone with more experience with the nuget.exe command-line tool (or writing extensions for it) have more insight into what the right route would be, or if there is an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up trying the first option, and it was easier than I initially thought. There is already support for updating to a specific version in the API, and I simply had to add a -Version option for the command line tool, and invoke it if specified.

I have created a fork of NuGet 2.8.2 with the change applied here: https://github.com/rikoe/nuget/tree/2.8.2.

I will try to submit a pull request to get it added to a future version of NuGet.